# Django filter table by foreign keys in related manager column

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-related-manager

I have three models in my Django application:

```
class MainData(models.Model):
    # bunch of fields

class Label(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True, unique=True)

class MapData(models.Model):
    labelMatch = models.ForeignKey(Label, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mainMatch = models.ForeignKey(MainData, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Through my application, I have the user enter a label in a search box. What I would like to do is return the `MainData` rows whos' `MapData.label_match` field is the entry in `Label`.

For example, say the user enters the string 'main32' into the search box. My current thought is to first find `Label` rows that match 'main32', then use the `RelatedManager` `labelmatch_set` to get all of the `MapData` rows that `MapData.mainMatch` points to. So if there are 10 MapData rows whose `labelMatch` points to a `Label` entry with `label='main32'`, I then want to retrieve all 10 `MainData` rows that the foreign key `mainMatch` points to.

Hopefully I explained that ok. I have gotten to:

```
matching_label_rows = Label.objects.filter(input)
matching_main_data_rows = matching_label_rows.mainMatch_set.????
```

How can I retrieve the pointed to `MainData` rows from `matching_label_rows.mainMatch_set`? And can this operation be done as a one-liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of finding the matching `Label`s first, you can filter `MainData` on the `mapdata__labelMatch` relationship:

```
matching_main_data_rows = MainData.objects.filter(mapdata__labelmatch__label__icontains=input)
```

[Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: This did the trick, thank you! I'm starting to see just how powerful Django really is